# AutomationPeer - how to show data of elements not on the control?

Tags: automation, accessibility, coded-ui-tests

I want to write an AutomationPeer for my custom control in WPF.

Now, I want to show textBlocks \ TextBoxex that are not actually visible on my control.
I know how to override the method GetChildrenCore().
My problem is that when i run the playback (coded ui record) - it's trying to find a control not vissible on the window. Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the SearchConfiguration VisibleOnly on the Coded UI control.  Also, the UITestControl.FindMatchingControls method can let you know if the search properties are too ambiguous.  Coded UI stops looking for a control after the first instance of a matching control is found.

inspect.exe can shed light on a form and how Coded UI may be seeing the control.

Try opening the Designer.cs and see the hierarchy and what Coded UI is trying to find.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I'm not working on a WinForms form, but on a Mainwindow of WPF. Can yop give an example in code? where is the file inspect.exe located?

Comment: Inspect location/information [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  Sorry, missed the WPF in the original question. I don't know if Coded UI behaves differently.

Comment: WpfButton button = new WpfButton();
   UITestControlCollection matchingButtons = button.FindMatchingControls();

Comment: button.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.VisibleOnly);